# Evga X58 SLI - deleted mbr now can't boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, mbr

Somehow, and I did not know this until reboot, my windows 7 pro system files were not on the same disk as the mbr disk the bios was booting from.

I ignorantly cleared off this "spare" drive and deleted the partition on it, since it would not let me format it.

I did not know it was the only bootable device the system had.

Now upon reboot it can't get to the drive my windows install is on, because that drive is not bootable. I did not know such a thing was even an allowed configuration.

This is my home computer.

My copy of Windows is on that same physical drive that I can't get to. It's a sata

I do have a sata to usb converter and I could burn a windows setup disk at work (I think).

I already tried booting from a 32 bit windows setup disk, but the screen never comes up.

System was running fine before I did this.

My first wish would be to make the system drive bootable and just boot
 into sata, since that's an SSD drive and should boot faster.

Also, maybe irrelevant, I'd like to leave out this old video card that is not being used, thAt the pc would not boot without it.

I am willing to lose my installation of windows. My documents are safe.

Comment: "I already tried booting from a 32 bit windows setup disk, but the screen never comes up." What you did would not cause this, this is your problem though, if you cannot boot from a setup disc, you cannot repair it or re-install the OS, something else is going on.

Comment: @Moab, Thank you Moab. You are correct. Is it possible that my mobo does not support making a sata device the bootable device? Note that the sata drive is #1 in the boot sequence. And a related question would be, if I take the sata out and make it bootable, should the mobo recognize it? I dont know if sata is like usb (a universal language) or if the mobo needs to find the driver somehow to even talk to it. You can probably see my confusion; I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: I had an older dell that would not let me boot from a sata hard drive when there was an ide hard drive connected, so I disconnected the ide drive and it booted from sata, then I shut down and connected the ide drive back and it continued to boot from sata, some weird bios problem.

Comment: @Moab, the solution was to remove all the other drives and install windows on the ssd I wanted windows to be on. Then I easily hooked up the other ssd's and chunked that old hdd. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ttoddmo you can answer your own question and get points.

Comment: @Moab, hey you should. You are the one who gave me the idea :) and thanks again!